How to Check if all Packages of a Nuget Package Repository exist in another Repository
I want to check if all nuget packages in a private Nuget Repository also exist in the nuget.org package repository.
Is there a way to go through all packages in the private Repo, check if they exist on nuget.org and get a list of those which are not available?
Contex:
Long ago the company I work for created a Proxy Nuget Repository to make sure packages will always be available.
Due to several changes in out infrastructure and moving many things from our own Severs to the cloud, we now want to get rid of that Proxy Repo as it is the last thing on our own Servers.
Since there is discussion about whether or not this Repo is needed, I want to check the availability for all packages.
The rough overview I could get manually seemed fine, but I couldn't google anything that helps me to automate this process.
